# How to transpose filtered data in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have created a table with the demo data, below:

[image]

I apply the filter "B!=0":

[image]

I then click and drag from A2-A7 in the filtered data, copy, and paste-transpose:

[image]

The output I get includes all of the fields I filtered out (values 4 and 5):
[image]

How do I copy and paste-transpose from a filtered list to get the output I expect (2,3,6,7)?

Comment: In case this is a bug, as per Adam Silenko's answer, this is from LibreOffice 5, version 5.3.1.2, Build ID: 1:5.3.1-0ubuntu2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is palpably bug. You can do normal paste (without transposition), then cut result and paste with transposition.

Comment: I agree that your paste-first, then copy/paste-transpose works. Is the above behavior actually a bug?

Comment: I didn’t find any bug reports for it